# DOMPDF is not producing correct output

Tags: codeigniter, dompdf

`DOMPDF` is producing only html path in pdf file instead of content at html path.

```
include_once('dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php'); 
$html= $this->load->view('view_pdf');
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html($html);
$dompdf->set_paper("a4", "landscape" ); 

$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream("my_pdf.pdf", array("Attachment" => 0));
```

If anybody have any idea please give here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [codeigniter docs](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html):

> **Returning views as data**
>
> There is a third **optional** parameter lets you change the behavior of
>   the function so that it returns data as a string rather than sending
>   it to your browser. This can be useful if you want to process the data
>   in some way. If you set the parameter to `true` (boolean) it will return
>   data. The default behavior is `false`, which sends it to your browser.
>   Remember to assign it to a variable if you want the data returned:
>
> ```
> $string = $this->load->view('myfile', '', true);
> ```

So your code should be:

```
include_once('dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php');
$html= $this->load->view('view_pdf','',true);
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html($html);
$dompdf->set_paper("a4", "landscape" );

$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream("my_pdf.pdf", array("Attachment" => 0));
```

Comment: I have written `true` but it is producing "html link" in pdf inspite of content at this link.

Comment: I'm not a user of CI, so I'll be of limited help from here on. It sounds like you need to address the issue on the CI side. If you `echo $html` after using `$this->load->view()` what do you see?

Answer (score 2):

You need the content of view_pdf to load as a string into $html:

```
$html = $this->load->view('view_pdf', '', true);
```

Comment: Somehow I missed your answer when I answered earlier ... so, upvote for being first.